# Debugging: How to debug and analyze concurrent protocols like Raft?

Tags: concurrency, debugging

How does one go about debugging concurrent protocols/concurrent algorithms in general?

I typically uses the built-in debugger from Intellij/Pycharm, but I find that it fails spectacularly when it comes to debugging concurrent apps.

What's the general recommended workflow for debugging and understanding how concurrent protocols are meant to work?

Comment: Question may be off topic for this site. Concrete tool questions fit better on StackOverflow

Comment: dont have any probs with c#, how does your debugger fail?

Comment: One suggestion is to log everything and then read the log to figure out what is going on - instead of trying to pause the program while it's running the protocol.

Answer (score 3):

As I do more concurrent programming, I have found myself relying mostly on unit tests for debugging. This makes it much easier to control the interactions and their timing.

When using a debugger, it's helpful to instead of stopping at breakpoints or single-stepping, set your breakpoint commands to quickly print something or change something then continue, so your timing isn't disrupted. You can also use conditional breakpoints to avoid stopping until the condition you are investigating has occurred.

Basically, if you stop at a breakpoint in a highly concurrent app, you should consider the state of the application broken, so you can examine the state right before you broke, but not really safely continue.

Answer (score 1):

Think about debugging as **hypothesis testing:**

- What hypotheses could explain the symptoms you're seeing? List as many as you can.
- How to test them? Think of ways to test them.

With concurrent programs, some of the hypotheses are ordinary **logic bugs in the components.**

These hypotheses should suggest non-concurrent unit tests, and you can single step though those tests.

If you don't know what cases to test, consider adding assertion checks or logging/print statements for the hypothetical cases that could lead to the observed symptoms.

If the program simply crashes without much information, try adding a fault handler or other way to get information like a stack trace when the problem occurs. This should help you come up with hypotheses to test.

The other hypotheses are **bugs in the concurrency control** such as:

- *race conditions* such as accessing mutable shared state without correct locking or other serialized access
- *deadlocking* when the code doesn't always grab locks in a consistent order
- *priority inversion* where a low priority operation holds a lock for a long time, making a high priority operation wait too long to meet its (realtime) deadlines.

Locks are notoriously difficult to get right.

Concurrency-control hypotheses are inherently harder to test because these problems will occur inconsistently depending on timing variations, and harder to debug because techniques like breakpoints will alter the timing.

Good techniques to test them include:

- logging (using a log facility or plain print statements)
- do a code review of the concurrency control
- rewrite this part of the code using less mutable shared data, or switch to atomic transactions or higher level concurrency control such as actor concurrency, or switch to a language like Clojure or Rust.

If your program has tight realtime deadlines such as video streaming or robot control, then printf statements might interfere too much with timing. In that case, you can log data to an in-memory ring buffer or send it to another CPU.

You'll also need to know the semantics of how concurrency works in your programming language. E.g. which operations are atomic, like reading/writing an `int` in Java? What's the memory model for data changes to be visible to another thread or process? How do the locks work and how do they get initialized?